# How does spring framework knows how to instantiate RestHighLevelClient in this example?

Tags: java, spring, resthighlevelclient

I'm following [this post](https://medium.com/@sourav.pati09/how-to-use-java-high-level-rest-client-with-spring-boot-to-talk-to-aws-elasticsearch-2b6106f2e2c) which explains how to use Java High Level REST Client (JHLRC) to connect with ElasticSearch.

The important parts for this questions are in [ElasticsearchConfig.java](https://github.com/spati-java/spring-boot-java-highlevel-rest-client-elasticsearch/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/example/aws/elasticsearch/demo/config/ElasticsearchConfig.java):

```java
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

    ...

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;

    }


}
```

and [ProfileService.java](https://github.com/spati-java/spring-boot-java-highlevel-rest-client-elasticsearch/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/example/aws/elasticsearch/demo/service/ProfileService.java):

```java
@Service
public class ProfileService {

    private RestHighLevelClient client;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    public ProfileService(RestHighLevelClient client, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.client = client;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    ...
```

We are autowiring `RestHighLevelClient` and `ObjectMapper`, so how does Spring knows that the `RestHighLevelClient` instance we need comes from `ElasticsearchConfig.restClient()`?

Comment: It looks for autowire candidates (instances of `RestHighLevelClient`) in the `ApplicationContext`, finds only one (no other instances pending creation, and one has already been made by the `@Bean` annotated method).  Since there's only one, it gets used.

Comment: `@Bean` annotated methods in `@Configuration` annotated classes will be invoked and the result loaded into the `ApplicationContext` (in case the confusion was there instead).

Comment: So, in case two or more methods inside any `@Configuration` component Spring return the same kind of object, will it report it? (as a warning or error?)

Comment: They can have multiple methods.  If multiple methods returned an instance of `RestHighLevelClient` then it would fail to create the `ProfileService` (too many candidates).  However you can get around this by marking one of them as `@Primary` (specifying this is preferred when there's multiple), or by specifying which one you want with an `@Value("beanName")` annotation on the parameter in your `ProfileService` constructor (by default the 'beanName' will be the same as the method name.  But you can specify this in the `@Bean` annotation).

Comment: @BeUndead: Thanks! your explanation is very clear to me. I suspected something like that, but I was not sure. Can you move your comments into an answer so I can accept it, please?

Comment: Done.  Sorry, I wanted to work out which aspect wasn't clear before writing one first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does an initial scan of the classes to identify what beans it is going to make.  It will then start the 'initialisation' phase.

`@Bean` annotated methods in `@Configuration` annotated classes will be invoked, and the result loaded into the `ApplicationContext`.  So the `RestHighLevelClient` is created (by the method you have) and loaded.

It then tries to create the `ProfileService` instance.  It sees that a `RestHighLevelClient` instance is required (by constructor parameter).  It looks in the `ApplicationContext` as well as the beans planned for creation in the scanning phase.  Since there's only *one* `RestHighLevelClient` instance there's no conflict, and so that instance is used.

---

From other comments:

If there are *multiple* `RestHighLevelClient` instances either pending creation or already in the `ApplicationContext` then you will get a `BeanCreationException` detailing that 'too many candidates, expected 1 but found *n*'.

These can be worked in several ways.

You can annotate *one* of the `RestHighLevelClient` beans as `@Primary` which indicates 'use this if multiple are available, but only one required'.

You can annotate the constructor parameter with an `@Qualifier` detailing *which* of the multiple instances to autowire.

You can change the constructor parameter to a `Collection<RestHighLevelClient>` which will autowire *all* such instances, and then make the selection yourself in the constructor.